# How to use the array passed in the constructor

Tags: php, constructor

I am confused about constructor. I need to pass an array to a class. I have at the moment 2 data to pass to the array.

Now from this array, I need to define `$this->m_id` and `$this->community_type` so that I can use these variables through out the class. Below is my example.

```
$arr = array('id'=>$u_id, 'community_type' => $community_type);
$rate = new Registration($arr);

class Registration{
    protected $m_id;
    protected $community_type;

    public function __construct(array $arr = array())
    {
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

I am looking to set

```
$this->m_id = $m_id;
$this->community_type = $community_type;
```

I tried using a `for` loop but I don't know something went wrong.
Can anybody help me

Comment: outside of the class, `$rate->id` and `$rate->community_type`

Comment: @Scuzzy i didnot get it can you please explain

Comment: Actually, you're going to run into issues with that `community_type` being set as `protected`, I missed that sorry. Wait for a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `$array[your_array_key]` as follow

```
public function __construct(array $arr = array())
{
    $this->m_id = $arr['id'];
    $this->community_type = $arr['community_type'];
}
```

Your existing code should work, if you are trying through loop, only problem I could notice is,

```
  protected $m_id;
```

You need to change this to

```
 protected $id;
```

Because, in your loop you are assuming your key is the member variable, which is actually not.

```
   foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $this->$key = $value;
    }
```

In you are array, your first key is `id` where as member variable declared as `m_id`, which is not matching.

Comment: i just include 2 items in the array but lets say i have many then what can i do

Comment: then you could loop it through. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

When run in the terminal, it shows that the object's properties are being created dynamically exactly as one would expect:

```
php > class Registration{
php {     protected $m_id;
php {     protected $community_type;
php { 
php {     public function __construct(array $arr = array())
php {     {
php {         foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
php {             $this->$key = $value;
php {         }
php {     }
php { }
php > $u_id = 'u_id value';
php > $community_type = 'community type value';
php > 
php > $arr = array('id'=>$u_id, 'community_type' => $community_type);
php > $rate = new Registration($arr);
php > 
php > var_dump($rate);
object(Registration)#1 (3) {
  ["m_id":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["community_type":protected]=>
  string(20) "community type value"
  ["id"]=>
  string(10) "u_id value"
}
```

I think there were several confounding factors that may have tripped you up:

1. Were the `$u_id` and `$community_type` variables assigned?  They weren't in your code.
2. There was some confusion about the variable names:  `$m_id` vs `$u_id`, `['id']` vs `$this->m_id`
3. Protected makes them harder access.

The var_dump shows that the keys of your array (`['id']` and `['community_type']` were indeed assigned as properties of the object.